# New to mesos/marathon. How to deploy a new self defined docker?

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

I am new to mesos and marathon.

I have a set up where in one docker is self defined and another is mysql server instance. These two are linked and pass information. How do I deploy this on mesos? I am using a single node master and slave set up currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To link your Docker containers use [Mesos-DNS](http://mesosphere.github.io/mesos-dns/). I'm using [Playa Mesos](https://github.com/mesosphere/playa-mesos) in the following to explain the setup.

Setting up Mesos-DNS on Playa is straightforward: use the [mesosphere/mesos-dns](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/mesosphere/mesos-dns/) image and deploy it on Marathon using the following app spec:

```
{
"id": "mesos-dns",
"instances": 1,
"cpus": 1,
"mem": 512,
"cmd": "/mesos-dns -config=/config.json",
"container": {
  "type": "DOCKER",
  "docker": {
    "image": "mesosphere/mesos-dns:latest",
    "network": "HOST"
 },
 "volumes": [
      {
        "containerPath": "/config.json",
        "hostPath": "/etc/mesos-dns/config.js",
        "mode": "RW"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With the following `config.js`:

```
{
 "zk": "zk://127.0.0.1:2181/mesos",
 "refreshSeconds": 60,
 "ttl": 60,
 "domain": "mesos",
 "port": 53,
 "resolvers": ["10.0.2.3"],
 "timeout": 5,
 "email": "root.mesos-dns.mesos"
}
```

Also, make sure that the `resolv.conf` has the right entry in first position:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 10.0.2.3
search net
```

You can then dynamically [discover](http://mesosphere.github.io/mesos-dns/docs/naming.html) your service (on the Vagrant box) as so:

```
dig _$APPID._tcp.marathon.mesos SRV
```

Where `$APPID` is the identifier you used to deploy your custom Docker image. The above command will tell you the IP and the port Marathon has assigned to your app. You can alternatively use the Mesos-DNS [HTTP API](http://mesosphere.github.io/mesos-dns/docs/http.html) for service discovery.

Note 1: the [DCOS](https://mesosphere.com/product) comes with Mesos-DNS pre-installed, so you can directly use it for service discovery.

Note 2: if you run into the issue that your app doesn't understand `SRV` records you can try this workaround: https://github.com/the-tetanus-clinic/srv-shim

Comment: Thanks. Explored Mesos-DNS and Consul. Apparently, the exposed port can only be accessed by SRV look ups, but this cannot be used inside the json script. Anyway, done for now. Will keep updated if and when I explore further.

Comment: Glad to hear this @208rishabh and please mark the answer as correct then. Also, a workaround for using existing apps with SRV record is https://github.com/the-tetanus-clinic/srv-shim

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas: I followed those exact steps in the context of your m-shop tutorial. Still, I get no answer from mesos-dns when running the dig command. Adding nameserver 127.0.0.1 to /etc/resolv.conf (or 10.141.141.10 for that matter) doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The [official Marathon documentation](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html) says that arbitrary docker commands are allowed in the parameters object (bottom of the doc page), so you could probably use that to connect them.

Alternatively [Mesos-DNS](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/service-discovery-load-balancing.html) seems to be a solution. The first solution should fail as soon as you move from a single host to multiple hosts and your single containers get scheduled to different hosts.

Note: I'm not very experienced with docker either, but these seem to be the only options I could find. However, integrating Docker into Mesos is an ongoing process and integrating Docker Swarm into Mesos is currently work in progress afaik, so these problems will probably we solved in the (hopefully near) future.