# Setting Mesos DNS on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dns, docker, mesos

I am trying to set up Mesos DNS after a few week of playing around with containers.
I got some trouble with the DNS, even if it is said to be 'light and easy' :-s
Following the docs : 
https://mesosphere.github.io/mesos-dns/docs/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ir3oo62I8n0

http://programmableinfrastructure.com/guides/service-discovery/mesos-dns-haproxy-marathon/

I got into several issue, the first of one being that port 53 is used by dnsmask under my ubuntu 14.04 system :

```
$ sudo docker run --net=host  -v "/etc/mesos-dns/config.json:/config.json" mesosphere/mesos-dns /mesos-dns -config=/config.json
ERROR: 2015/11/11 13:30:34 generator.go:74: no master
ERROR: 2015/11/11 13:30:34 main.go:65: DNS server failed: Failed to setup "tcp" server: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:53: bind: address already in use

$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 53
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1866/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           553/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40367           0.0.0.0:*                           553/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           1866/dnsmasq    
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                553/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::60577                :::*                                553/avahi-daemon: r
```

I am not sure what to do next ?

I also had a look to:

[Setup Mesos-DNS dockerized on a mesos cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401101/setup-mesos-dns-dockerized-on-a-mesos-cluster)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of dnsmasq: `sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq stop` and then port `53` is available for Mesos-DNS.

Comment: won't that kill all my network ressources ? Like wifi access  ?

Comment: Yup, that was a bit too agressive, sry. Updating the post.

Comment: Apparantly you also have problems with connecting to the Mesos Master? And setting the port to 54 will probably probably not work without passing the explicit port number to all the "client applications" which want to make use of Mesos DNS...

Comment: @Tobi that's why I suggested to get rid of dnsmasq … ;)

Comment: I am now on a ubuntu server distrib. [sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq stop] doesn't even work => [sudo: /etc/init.d/dnsmasq: command not found]