# Why does Mesos-DNS not provide a SRV answer?

Tags: dns, mesos, mesosphere

I have a vagrant box which is running Mesos, Marathon and Chronos (publicly packaged as `playa-mesos`). It is a sane environment (I have customized to a 192.168.*.* ip address though) and I can launch different apps incl. docker containerized ones.
I have tried a new demo, where there is a DNS requirement and the mesos application launch definition is as below :

```
{
 "id": "mesos-dns",
 "instances": 1,
 "cpus": 0.2,
 "mem": 50,
 "cmd": "/mesos-dns -config=/config.json",
 "container": {
  "type": "DOCKER",
  "docker": {
  "image": "mesosphere/mesos-dns:latest",
  "network": "HOST"
},
"volumes": [
  {
    "containerPath": "/config.json",
    "hostPath": "/etc/mesos-dns/config.json",
    "mode": "RO"
  }
]
}
}
```

The `config.json` is as under :

```
{
"zk": "zk://127.0.0.1:2181/mesos",
"refreshSeconds": 60,
"ttl": 60,
"domain": "mesos",
"port": 53,
"resolvers": ["10.0.2.3"],
"timeout": 5,
"email": "root.mesos-dns.mesos"
}
```

The `/etc/resolv.conf` contains `nameserver 10.0.2.3`

Below is the `dig` response I get to my DNS query; both are shown below :-

```
dig _webdis-site-m-shop._tcp.marathon.mesos SRV

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.1-Ubuntu <<>> _webdis-site-m-shop._tcp.marathon.mesos SRV
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 4759
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 8192
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_webdis-site-m-shop._tcp.marathon.mesos. IN SRV

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       56521   IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2016021800 1
800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 155 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.2.3#53(10.0.2.3)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 18 13:38:21 UTC 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 143`
```

As you can see there is **no** `ANSWER` and the status `NXDOMAIN` means that this query resulted in a non-existent domain.

Can someone help me fix this ?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed. I have taken some thoughts from other posts on SO. I have changed the OOTB setting for ip address etc...
Broadly I added the 127.0.0.1 loopback ip addr, virtualbox generated ip addr (which in my case is 192.168.x.y) and retained the existing nameserver entry.
The results of the dig command is now :-

```
dig _webdis-site-m-shop._tcp.marathon.mesos SRV

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.1-Ubuntu <<>> _webdis-site-m-shop._tcp.marathon.mesos SRV
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6284
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_webdis-site-m-shop._tcp.marathon.mesos. IN SRV

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_webdis-site-m-shop._tcp.marathon.mesos. 60 IN SRV 0 0 31720 webdis-site-m-shop-39847-s0.marathon.mesos.


;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
webdis-site-m-shop-39847-s0.marathon.mesos. 60 IN A 192.168.56.106

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 18 16:55:57 UTC 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 216
```

Comment: Answered by @Tobi here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401101/setup-mesos-dns-dockerized-on-a-mesos-cluster

Comment: Glad you could use my answer!

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your answer ? I am experiencing the same issue but I can't figure what you mean by "I added 127.0.0.1 loopback ip add". Thanks

Comment: Can you specifically call out what the problem is in one sentence ? I had multiple problems which I was addressing at the time when I raised this on SO. The related issue (now closed) can be seen @ https://github.com/mhausenblas/m-shop/issues/4. The 127..1 aka loopback note above relates to changes in my `/etc/hosts` file (I think).